# How put parameter to get request?

Tags: java, android, get, retrofit2

It tries to display a list of notes to which the user is assigned by means of the GET command. From the PHP side everything works but I do not know how to program it in the android studio? How put parameter to GET request?

```
 @GET("allnotesuser/{user}")
    Call<NotesUserResponse> getAllNotesUser(
            @Path("user") int user
    );
```

UsersFragment

```
  @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        User user = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getActivity()).getUser();

        Call<NotesUserResponse> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getAllNotesUser(user.getusers_id());

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_notes_user);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));



        call.enqueue(new Callback<NotesUserResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<NotesUserResponse> call, Response<NotesUserResponse> response) {

                notesUserList= response.body().getAllNotesUser();
                adapterNotesUser = new NotesUserAdapter(getActivity(),notesUserList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterNotesUser);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<NotesUserResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
        }
```

In this line i got error "revylerview.setLayoutManager is null"

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```